# How to update application id of Android app which is already installed in user's device?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android application developed in Android Studio which is deployed on production server. I want to update the application id of the application.

Now the problem is this when users download the new application then two application will be visible on their devices as application id is different in new version.

Is their any way by which new application will replace the existing application?

Comment: There is no way .. These are two different apps now and u can not do anything about this .

Comment: You still can update app A to suggest download and installation of app B, then app B will suggest uninstallation of app A. App A can even expose data for app B to allow migration.